# Почему не работает бот ? В самом Python ошибку не отображает

Tags: python, telebot

Код запускается но отклика у самого бота нет.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ss')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def welcome (message):

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Music1")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Music2")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Music3")

    markup.add ("item1")
    markup.add ("item2")
    markup.add ("item3")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"qq1".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def send_audio(user_id):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Music1':
            audio = open(r'C:/Users/artsa/Downloads/qq1.mp3', 'rb')
            bot.send_audio(chat.id, audio)

        elif message.text == 'Music2':
            audio = open(r'C:/Users/artsa/Downloads/qq2.mp3', 'rb')
            bot.send_audio(chat.id, audio)

        elif message.text == 'Music3':
            audio = open(r'C:/Users/artsa/Downloads/qq3.mp3', 'rb')
            bot.send_audio(chat.id, audio)

        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'zaebalo')

        bot.polling(none_stop=True,)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код запускается но отклика у самого бота нет.

Answer (score 1):

Отступ в `bot.polling(none_stop=True,)` неправильно поставлен. Если исправите,  то он заработает. А так он находится в ветвлении if-elif-else, поэтому код не работает

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def send_audio(user_id):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Music1':
            audio = open(r'C:/Users/artsa/Downloads/qq1.mp3', 'rb')
            bot.send_audio(chat.id, audio)

        elif message.text == 'Music2':
            audio = open(r'C:/Users/artsa/Downloads/qq2.mp3', 'rb')
            bot.send_audio(chat.id, audio)

        elif message.text == 'Music3':
            audio = open(r'C:/Users/artsa/Downloads/qq3.mp3', 'rb')
            bot.send_audio(chat.id, audio)

        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'zaebalo')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```